# Import tensorflow error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Xbyak::Error'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to debug an error with tensorflow. When I import tensorflow
I get the following error

> import tensorflow as tf
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Xbyak::Error'
>
> what():  internal error
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Here are the install details

OS >> Ubuntu 14.04

Install Method Anaconda >> conda 4.4.11  (conda install tensorflow)

python3 --version  >>  Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.

If anyone has experience or knowledge on how to fix this issue, I would be most grateful.  A search here, on google and on github yielded suggested [the issue is likely with MKL-DNN](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2908), has anyone found a work around?

Comment: FYI, I didn't have any issues installing it on Ubuntu 16.04 or 12.04 using the same method.

Comment: I get the same Issue. OS: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia; Install Method Anaconda (4.4.11, conda install tensorflow); python3 --version: Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc. What CPU do you have? " It seems MKL-DNN has some checks that failed and throw Xbyak::Error when running on Ryzen. CNTK's build/test environment does not have Ryzen CPUs so this is not caught before release." from the Github Issue you linked. I have a Ryzen CPU

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, it is probably a better practice to install from source using official documentation:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#installing_with_anaconda

That's the only method which google supports.

The conda forge version (1.5.0) works fine. Using

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

p.s.: Make sure you don't edit as that will throw back the original error.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, I had the same problem as you. Anaconda seems to not fully support tensorflow or have an older version, because when I installed tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow` I had no problems. I hope this solves it for you as well.

Comment: Thanks Fritz Fruit, for the moment I am using my other computers anaconda worked great for Ubuntu 12.04 and 16.04 but not 14.04.  But if I need it on my home desktop I will use that.

Answer (score 0):

Even I kept getting this error when I created another environment and installed TF in it. Seems like Tensorflow is the main issue here. What did solve my problem was I simply installed Tensorflow using this command `pip3 install tensorflow`. I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same error using the conda distribution. Tried the source forge version and it worked great. but the conda is TF 1.7 and the source forge is 1.5.